# AttributeError converting Python function from SQLite DB to use geopackage in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, pyqt5

I would like to change my functions in PyQGIS from SQLite databases to Geopackages. However, the SQL statements don't quite work as I had hoped. My table has the columns: *task, completed, date*
With SQLITE the following function works as intended (see comments) with the Geopackage I get the following error message: **AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'fetchedRowCount'.**

What am I doing wrong?

working solution shows checkbox in the ListWidget, geopackage Version does not:

[image]

[image]

```
def updateList(self, date):
    self.tasksListWidget.clear()
    md = QgsProviderRegistry.instance().providerMetadata("ogr")
    con = md.createConnection( dbfile, {})

    # db = lite.connect(dbfile)
    # cursor = db.cursor()

    row = (date,)
    query = 'SELECT task, completed FROM tasks WHERE date ="%s"' %(row)
    
    # results = cursor.execute(query, row).fetchall()

    results = con.executeSql(query).fetchedRowCount()
    
    for result in results:
        item = QListWidgetItem(str(result[0]))
        item.setFlags(item.flags() | Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)
        if result[1] == "YES":
            item.setCheckState(Qt.Checked)
        elif result[1] == "NO":
            item.setCheckState(Qt.Unchecked)
        self.tasksListWidget.addItem(item)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>You need to use [`execSql`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsAbstractDatabaseProviderConnection.html#a265e4396556fb0c02e4a4744e32e1238) instead of [`executeSql`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsAbstractDatabaseProviderConnection.html#a8e8f6aa6edb10855ad54429bb82f6a01) to use `fetchedRowCount()` which belongs to `QueryResult` class. `execSql` returns [`QueryResult`](https://api.qgis.org/api/structQgsAbstractDatabaseProviderConnection_1_1QueryResult.html). `executeSql` returns a list.</s>

Because `results` must be iterable, you want to iterate over the data returned from the sql query. Therefore, you need the line below (remove `.fetchedRowCount()`):

```
results = con.executeSql(query)
```

Comment: Your right, i used the wrong executeSql. Unfortunately, I now get TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable... Any guess?
I always thought Geopackage is based on a sqlite DB, too bad that you have to adapt the code anyway.

Comment: OK.  Please check my edit. I have no chance to test the script.

Comment: Thank you! The .fetchall() of the sqlite code irritated me. results = con.executeSql(query) without .fetchedRowCount() works.